# unable to translate LINQ expression to find people in specified list of locations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC I am trying to find the people in any of the locations.  There are 2 contexts pointing to 2 databases on 2 SQL Servers, if that matters. The IFSODPeopleRepository contains tables from SQL1, The UserFacilities is populated by executing a stored proc in SQL2 via the MasterContext.

Given the entity, `People.Location` property has values of

```
{"??? New York ???", "???? Seattle", "Boston ?????"}
```

and the search criteria is a

```
List<string> { "Chicago", "Seattle", "Dallas" }
```

The following code doesn't throw an exception when running on my development machine in Visual Studio with IIS Express.  It throws an exception when running in IIS server if the filtering of the people
///// code block ///// is added. I also test hard coded the loc variable value with "Seattle" and it works for both environments.  Thanks.

```cs
try 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria)) 
    {
        // default on page load
        people = await _peopleRepository.FindByCondition(x => previousQuarter == x.FiscalPeriodInt)
                                        .Select(p => HydrateDTO.HydratePeople(p))
                                        .ToListAsync();
    }
    .... code omitted
    .... code omitted


///// removal of the following code block then IIS host server doesn't throw exception     
    /* approach 1: doesn't work on IIS, but work on Visual Studio with IISExpress*/
    /* people = people.Where(x => userFacilities.Any(fac => 
    x.Facility.Contains(fac))); */

    /* approach 2: hard code the value works on both IIS and Visual Studio with IISExpress */
    /* people = people.Where(x => userFacilities.Any(fac => 
    x.Facility.Contains("Seattle"))); */

    /* approach 3: doesn't work on IIS but works on Visual Studio*/
    List<PeopleDTO> viewablePeople = new List<PeopleDTO>();
    foreach(var p in people)
    {
      foreach(var loc in locations)
      {
        /* approach 3A: doesn't work on IIS but works on Visual Studio*/
        if (p.Location.IndexOf(loc) != -1) 
        
        /* approach 3B: works on both IIS and Visual Studio*/
        /*if (p.Location.IndexOf("Seattle") != -1) */
        {
          viewablePeople.Add(p);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    people= null;
    people= viewablePeople;
///// end of code removal to satisfy IS host environment

    return people;
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    throw;
}
```

launchSettings.json

```js
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:30667",
      "sslPort": 44381
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "ancmHostingModel": "InProcess",
      "use64Bit": true
    },
    "IPR": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

MVC Controller.cs

```js
namespace IPR.Controllers
{
  //ToDo: [Authorize]
  public class PeopleController : BaseController
  {
    ILogger<PeopleController> _logger;
    public PeopleController(ILogger<PeopleController> logger, IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {
      _logger = logger;
    }

    // GET: PeopleController
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string criteria)
    {
      ViewBag.Title = "People";
      List<PeopleDTO> people = new List<PeopleDTO>();

      string sessionCriteria;
      string sessionKey = "SearchCriteria";
      CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
      await HttpContext.Session.LoadAsync(cancellationToken);
      sessionCriteria = HttpContext.Session.GetString(sessionKey);
      if (criteria != sessionCriteria)
      {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria))
          HttpContext.Session.Remove(sessionKey);
        else
          HttpContext.Session.SetString(sessionKey, criteria);
      }

      ViewBag.PreviousCriteria = criteria;

      HttpResponseMessage Res;

      string url = string.Empty;
      try
      {
        //Sending request to find web api REST service resource FSODPeople using HttpClient in the APIAgent
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria))
        {
          url = $"{_apiBaseUrl}/api/FSODPeople";
          Res = await APIAgent.GetDataAsync(new Uri(url));
        }
        else
        {
          url = $"{_apiBaseUrl}/api/FSODPeople?criteria={criteria}&withEpisode=true";
          Res = await APIAgent.GetDataAsync(new Uri(url));
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        return PartialView("_ErrorPartial", new ErrorViewModelHelper()
          .Create("Fail to call Web API", ex.Message, ex.InnerException?.Message));
      }

      string httpMsgContentReadMethod = "ReadAsStreamAsync";
      System.IO.Stream contentStream = null;
      if (Res.Content is object && Res.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/json")
      {
        try
        {
          switch (httpMsgContentReadMethod)
          {
            case "ReadAsAsync":
              people = await Res.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<PeopleDTO>>();
              break;

            //use .Net 5 built-in deserializer
            case "ReadAsStreamAsync":
              contentStream = await Res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
              people = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<PeopleDTO>>(contentStream, _options);
              break;
          }

          if (people?.Count == 0)
            return View("_NoDataPartial");

          //returning the question list to view  
          return View(people);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)// Could be ArgumentNullException or UnsupportedMediaTypeException
        {
          return PartialView("_ErrorPartial", new ErrorViewModelHelper()
            .Create("Json deserialization error", ex.Message, ex.InnerException?.Message));
        }
      }
      else
      {
        var ex = new Exception();
        return PartialView("_ErrorPartial", new ErrorViewModelHelper()
        .Create("Web API content is not an object or mededia type is not applicaiton/json", string.Empty, string.Empty));
      }
    }
```

The APIAgent.cs

```cs
public static class APIAgent
{
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDataAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

        handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        using var client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var httpResponseMsg = await client.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

        //httpResponseMsg.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return httpResponseMsg;
    }
}
```

MVCBaseController.cs

```js
namespace IPR.Controllers
{
  public class BaseController : Controller
  {
    protected IIdentity _windowsIdentity;
    protected readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    protected readonly string _apiBaseUrl;
    protected readonly string _appVersion;
    protected readonly JsonSerializerOptions _options;
    protected readonly string sessionKey = "UserAccessLevels";

    protected BaseController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      _configuration = configuration;
      _apiBaseUrl = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").GetValue<string>("WebAPIBaseUrl");
      _appVersion = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").GetValue<string>("Version");
      _options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
      {
        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
        WriteIndented = true,
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
        IgnoreNullValues = true
      };
    }

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
      _windowsIdentity = HttpContext.User.Identity;
      ViewBag.WindowsIdentityName = _windowsIdentity.Name;
      ViewBag.AppVersion = $"Version {_appVersion}";
      await next();
    }
  }
}
```

WebAPIController.cs

```js
namespace IPRWebAPI2.Controllers
{
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class FSODPeopleController : ControllerBase
  {
    private readonly IFSODPeopleRepository _peopleRepository;
    private readonly IEpisodeRepository _episodeRepository;
    private readonly MasterContext _masterContext;
    public FSODPeopleController(IFSODPeopleRepository peopleRepository, IEpisodeRepository episodeRepository, MasterContext masterContext)
    {
      _peopleRepository = peopleRepository;
      _episodeRepository = episodeRepository;
      _masterContext = masterContext;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// get people matching the criteria and limit to user facility level
    /// do not across facility boundary unless the user has access level beyond facility level
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="criteria"></param>
    /// <param name="withEpisode"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    // GET: api/People
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PeopleDTO>>> GetPeople(string criteria, bool withEpisode)
    {
      //internally retrieve windows identity from User.Claims
      string networkName = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(networkName))
      {
        return NotFound("Windows Identity is null.  Make sure the service allows Windows Authentication");
      }

      var cacheHelper = new CacheHelper(); 
      var userAccessLevels = await cacheHelper.GetUserAccessLevels(_mastersContext, networkName);
      var userFacilities = userAccessLevels.Select(x => x.Facility).Distinct().ToList();

      if (userFacilities?.Count == 0)
      {
        return BadRequest("You are not permitted to view any location's people");
      }
      else
      {
        int[] quarters = new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1 };
        var currentQuarterNumber = quarters[DateTime.Today.Month - 1];

        int defaultQuarter = int.Parse($"{DateTime.Today.Year}{currentQuarterNumber}"); //result like 20213, 20221

        IEnumerable<PeopleDTO> people = null;
        try
        {
          people = await cacheHelper.GetPeople(_peopleRepository, defaultQuarter, criteria/*, userFacilities*/);

          //people = people.Where(x => userFacilities.Any(y => EF.Functions.Like(x.Facility, y)));
          people = people.Where(x => userFacilities.Any(fac => x.Facility.Contains(fac)));

          //List<PeopleDTO> viewablePeople = new List<PeopleDTO>();
          //foreach (PeopleDTO p in people)
          //{
          //  foreach (string fac in userFacilities)
          //  {
          //    if (pat.Location.IndexOf(fac) >= 0)
          //    {
          //      viewablePeople.Add(p);
          //      break;
          //    }
          //  }
          //}

          if (withEpisode)
          {
            foreach (var p in people)
            {
              List<EpisodeDTO> episodes = await _episodeRepository.FindByCondition(p =>
                p.PeopleIcnfkNavigation.Icn == p.PeopleIcnfk).Select(e => HydrateDTO.HydrateEpisode(e)).ToListAsync();
              p.Episodes = episodes;
            }
          }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
          throw;
        }
      return Ok(people);
      //return Ok(viewablePeople)
      }
    }
```

```js
    public static PeopleDTO HydratePeople(FSODPeopleDetailFY21Q2 p)
    {
      return new PeopleDTO
      {
        V = p.V,
        Location = p.Location,
        District = p.District,
        Division = p.Division,
        ADMParent_Key = p.ADMParent_Key,
        Sta6aKey = p.Sta6aKey,
        Bedsecn = p.bedsecn,
        Name = p.Name,
        PSSN = string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.PTFSSN) ? string.Empty : $"{p.PTFSSN}",
        FSODSSN = string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.FSODSSN) ? string.Empty : $"{p.PTFSSN}",
        FiscalPeriod = p.FiscalPeriod,
        FiscalPeriodInt = p.FiscalPeriodInt
      };
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more information. Sample data would be helpful. Also "string containing search string in the middle" sounds like it needs some data design.

Comment: Also your code sample looks incomplete

Comment: Please mention the version of ef core you're using.

Comment: Please only show the relevant code and tell where the exception is thrown (which line) and show the exception type + exact message.

Comment: @Gert Arnold, please see the updated post and the comment in ///// block /////.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 3 things here. I suggest using the option number 3 as client side evaluation causes memory leak as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#potential-memory-leak-in-client-evaluation).

1. Do client side evaluation for this specific query

   ```
   people = await _peopleRepository.FindByCondition(x => previousQuarter == 
   x.FiscalPeriodInt))
   .Select(p => 
    HydrateDTO.HydratePeople(p)).AsEnumerable().Any(x=>x.Location.Contains(l)).ToListAsync();
   ```
2. Allow client side evaluation for All queries (not recommended)

   ```
   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
   {
         optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlServer(@"Server(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFQuerying;Trusted_Connection=True;")
        .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => 
         warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
   ```

}

3. Use `EF.Functions.Like`

   ```
      people = await _peopleRepository.FindByCondition(x => 
          previousQuarter == x.FiscalPeriodInt 
          && locations.Any(l => EF.Functions.Like(x.Location,$"%{l}%")))
         .Select(p => HydrateDTO.HydratePeople(p)).ToListAsync();
   ```

Comment: Thank you. How do I do like any of the searched string with the EF.Functions? Calling the Like() multiple times with OR operator?  Should the expression be var likeExpression = "%" + name + "%"?

Comment: @user266909, I've updated the third option according to your code. please try this one.

Comment: Thank you.  I applied the 3rd method as described.  I still get the same error that the expression can not be translated.
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<PeopleFY21Q2>()
    .Where(f => __currentQuarter_0 == f.FiscalPeriodInt && __locations_1
        .Any(x => __Functions_2
            .Like(
                matchExpression: f.Location, 
                pattern: string.Format(
                    format: "%{0}%", 
                    arg0: x))))' could not be translated

Comment: @user266909, could you please share the static method HydratePeople that you used on the select query.

Comment: strangely the EF seems to only accept a constant such as "648" in userFacilities.Any(fac=>x.Facility.Contains("648"))) but not the variable value userFacilities.Any(fac=>x.Facility.Contains(fac)))